# EOF although I have retyped it in a different file

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

I am getting

> File "getweather.py", line 15 SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while
>   parsing

I retyped it into a new completely new file. But am still seeing the same issue. Can anyone see what could be causing it?

```
from urlib.request import urlopen
import json
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

try:
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=myapp user=postgres password=postgres")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = "select city from myapp"
    cursor.execute(query)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in data:
        print (row)
    db.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a `try` clause without an accompanying `except`; that's the cause of your error.

See the docs on [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.